# How to call onDraw() of a class extending GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, opengl-es

How do I call onDraw() on my class extending GLSurfaceView. I need the canvas for drawing the gestures of the user. (FingerPaint.java logic). Mean while I need the onDrawFrame() of the renderer to be called for other effects. I can manage the calls to both the methods by maintaing a flag. I am calling invalidate() but that too is not able to call the onDraw(). GLSurfaceView extends View so I thought I can override onDraw() and can call it by calling invalidate(). Please Throw some light. Thanks in Advance Krishna :)

Comment: It will automatically call when you set Render class to it

Comment: When we set Render class then onDrawFrame() is called. I want onDraw() to be called which is present in my class extending GLSurfaceView

Answer (score 2):

Try calling **requestRender ()** from your GLSurfaceView.
Obviously this works best when setting rendermode to "RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY".
And that means you won't be rendering continuously, so that may interfere with the "constant" rendering required for your effects.

I think the best solution would be to split the rendering up between 2 overlaying surfaces and 2 renderers. Request the bottom surface (fingerpaint surface) to render a frame whenever the user interacts, and on the top one (gfx surface) you render continuously. Or swap this around... whatever works best.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for taking pain to answer. :) Actually I am using GLSurfaceView and its renderer for showing pageTurn effects. I want to use onDraw(final Canvas c) for FingerPaint.java logic i.e. user scribbling. Now I want the scribbled paths also to also have the effect of turning with the page. so I want to do the page turn and scribbling on the same bitmap.

Comment: You could render the user scribbles to a texture and then use that texture when you render the page turn.

Comment: I don’t think you are allowed to have multiple SurfaceViews, at least pre-Android-4. So you will have to do your own off-screen compositing.

Answer (score 1):

Just call invalidate() and onDraw() will be called, just like normal View. The canvas is drawn on top of the GLES viewport.

So far I couldn't implement invalidate(Rect dirty). The whole view is redrawn always.

It is needed to put setWillNotDraw(false) before drawing.